# Changing the template engine of a project from savant2 to plates

Tags: php, templates, template-engine, plates, savant3

I am having a problem converting an old project that uses **savant2** template engine to **plates** template engine, I have gone through the platesphp documentation, and it is still confusing.
 The project in savant2 template is structured this way(example), first file

```
$savant = new Savant2();
$savant->addPath('template', [LINK TO TEMPLATE OR THEME]);
```

Then in other file, where the needed variables are declared

```
global $savant;
$my_name = "Victor";
$savant->assign('name', $my_name);
$savant->display('include/header.tmpl.php');
```

Then, in the header.tmpl.php file

```
<?php echo $this->name; ?>
```

Now, I want to use plates template engine instead to replace savant2, this is how my code is now structure, first file

```
$plates  = new League\Plates\Engine();
$plates->addFolder('template', [LINK TO TEMPLATE OR THEME]);
```

In the other file,

```
global $plates;
$my_name = "Victor";
$plates->addData('name', $my_name);
$plates->render('include/header.tmpl.php');
```

Then, In the header.tmpl.php file

```
<?=$this->e($name)?>
```

Though it is not working as expected, my confusion lies in the use of render,addData, and addFolder to produce the same results as savant2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it

```
    //Location of savant2 library
      require('/Savant2/Savant2.php');
    // set default template paths: 
      $savant = new Savant2();
      $savant->addPath('template', '/themes/');
```

Replace the above, and add this instead

```
    // Enable the composer autoload file (Depending on how your system is set up)
     require_once '/vendor/autoload.php';
     $plates = League\Plates\Engine::create('/themes/', 'tmpl.php');
```

Then for the below savant2 implementation

```
    require 'config.php';

    $name = 'Victor Alagwu';
    $school = 'University of Nigeria, Nsukka';
    $course = 'Computer Science';
    $savant->assign('author', $name);
    $savant->assign('school', $school);
    $savant->assign('course' $course);
    $savant->display(home.tmpl.php);
```

Replace it with this plates implementation

```
    require 'config.php';
    $name = 'Victor Alagwu';
    $school = 'University of Nigeria, Nsukka';
    $course = 'Computer Science';

    plate['name'] = $name;
    plate['school'] = $school;
    plate['course'] = $course;

    echo $plates->render('home.tmpl.php', $plate);
```

Then for the template files (Savant2)

```
       Name:
       <?php echo $this->name; ?>
       Course:
       <?php echo $this->course; ?>
       School: 
       <?php echo $this->school; ?>
```

Replace with the below (For Plates)

```
    Name:
     <?php echo $name; ?>
    Course:
    <?php echo $course; ?>
    School: 
    <?php echo $school; ?>
```

And there you have your previously savant2 app, now running on plates template engine